# How change height windows in WPF according to UserControl?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, user-controls

I have two "UserControl" each UserControl have different height.I put this UserControl in the same window, but in different time, the problem is how change height window dynamically according to height UserControl.

First UserControl is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="auto" Width="auto">
 <Grid  Height="auto" Width="360" .....  >
     <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20.8"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="18.4"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20.8"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  Text="xx" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ......./>
                <TextBlock  Text="yyy" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ...... />
                                                 ............
                                                 ............
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Secound UserControl is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             Height="auto" Width="auto">
 <Grid  Height="auto" Width="360" .....  >
     <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="17*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  Text="xx" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ......./>
                <TextBlock  Text="yyy" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                                                 ............
    </Grid>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        x:Class="MainWindow"
        Title="Home" Height="550"*** Width="700" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ....>
 <Grid Name="Move">
    <Button Content="xxx"   Height="28" TextBlock.FontSize="15" Name="btn1" Click="click1"/>
    <Button Content="yyy"  Grid.Row="1" Name="btn2" Click="click2"/>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

In Behind code MainWindow:

```
  private void click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl1 add = new UserControl1();
            Move.Children.Clear();
            Move.Children.Add(add);
        }

        private void click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UserControl2 add = new UserControl2();
            Move.Children.Clear();
            Move.Children.Add(add);
        }
```

Comment: can you try in code behind do something like:Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = add.Height;
And have you tried on main window put the Height auto?

Comment: thank you for help me can you write answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try in code behind do something like:Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = add.Height; And have you tried on main window put the Height auto?

regards,